# NSCollection view background color filling entirely

Tags: xcode, cocoa, background-color, nscollectionview

I have NSCollectionView and would like to set its background color, however using some of codes suggested here on stack I came to a problem - none of them fill the window entirely. You might be able to see a white (around 1px) white border around nscollection view except of the corners (collection view constraints are set to 0).

Ideally I would like to get rid of the white border.

Code for the first image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef) [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.227,0.251,0.337,1);
CGContextFillRect(context, NSRectToCGRect(dirtyRect));
}
```

[image: First Image]

Code for the second image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
[[NSColor blueColor] setFill];
NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Autolayout turned on? Any project warning? Go to MainMenu.xib and look in the right info panel. If Yes, then do something with the constraints.